# IF Statement inside a ChoiceType Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How do i place a IF Statement inside a ChoiceType to add another option?

This is the code:

```
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('Name', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Server' => 'Server',
                'APC' => 'APC',
                'Switch' => 'Switch',
                'APC Small' => 'APC Small'
            ),
```

The Choice `APC` need to be checked first to see if it exists. If it does not exists than it had to be included otherwise excluded.

The check is ready with a true and a false but how do i place a if statement inside the form add array. Or is there a other way to do that?

The if statement is something like this:

```
if($APCDisable == false){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem, but you can simply determine/calculate the choices array content before adding it to the form, for example like this

```
// initially w/out APC
$choices = [
    'Server' => 'Server',
    'Switch' => 'Switch',
    'APC Small' => 'APC Small'
];
if($APCDisable == false) {
    // add APC choice, since it's available
    $choices['APC'] = 'APC';
}
$form->add('Name', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => $choices,
]);
```

If you can calculate `$APCDisable` **only** based on the form data, then you can use form events like described in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method that return the array of choices.

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('Name', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => methodToRetrieveTheChoices(),
            ),
```

And in this method you can put the logic that you propose.